# modx redirect infinite loop

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

I am using Modx revolution latest version. i want to create a plugin it will check current page url. some cases when current url match a given pattern then i want to redirect to a new url.

My first query is: if i go  **www.mydomain.com/wrong-uri**  and wrong-uri is not exists it goes to **www.mydomain.com**.in that case if my current url is  **www.mydomain.com/wrong-uri**  then what will be resource id ???

my second query is:  
 i've done this  :

```
if ($modx->event->name == 'OnWebPagePrerender'){
$id = $modx->resource->get('id');
$curUrl = $modx->runSnippet('getCurrentPage',array('id' =>$id)); 
$output = &$modx->resource->_output;
$redUrl ="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/custom/';             
if(($curUrl !=$redUrl)&&  $curUrl == ("http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/")){



$modx->sendRedirect($redUrl);               
}
return ;
}
```

browser says that is in infinite redirect loop.why?

is this plugin called multiple times?? then what would be the appropriate event for this plugin ?? thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes i got it after all day ....!!!
for www.mydomain.com/wrong-uri  my $curUrl is www.mydomain.com/. so always if getting true and i'm in infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

If i go **www.mydomain.com/wrong-uri** and wrong-uri is not exists it goes to the page with id specified in the system setting `error_page`. And maybe http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Plugins#Plugins-PageNotFoundRedirector%3A will help.